# Pulling images into QTWidget (plugin dialog box) from web server?

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to show images in a dialogue box (built using QT Creator and interacted with through my plugin).  I have the images as a list of URLs, but can't figure out how to get them to display in the dialogue box. I thought perhaps I could just include an HTML image tag, but that just shows a file icon.

I wonder if I need to download them into a temp filestore first.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to have a QWebView ([loadHtml method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtwebview-webview.html#loadHtml-method)).
In Qt Designer, the QWebView doesn't appear and as workaround, create a QWidget, and in the Python code, create an QWebView object and add it with the `self.myQWidgetObject.layout().addWidget(self.myQWebViewObject)` [method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addWidget).

Obviously, the html code to load is with the `img` [html tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_diffloc).